# Laravel - Where Clause not working

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-5, query-builder

I am trying to build a search form with laravel, but I cannot get the where clause to work.

```
$term = $request->input('term');

$count = DB::table('members as m')
         ->where(DB::raw('m.member_first_name'), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
         ->orWhere(DB::raw('m.member_last_name'), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
         ->orWhere(DB::raw('m.member_business_address'), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
         ->orWhere(DB::raw("concat('m.member_first_name',' ','m.member_last_name')"), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
         ->orWhere(DB::raw("concat('m.member_last_name',' ','m.member_first_name')"), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
         ->orWhere(DB::raw("concat('m.member_name_affix',' ','m.member_last_name',' ','m.member_first_name')"), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
         ->orWhere(DB::raw("concat('m.member_first_name',' ','m.member_name_affix',' ','m.member_last_name')"), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
         ->count();

var_dump($count);
```

**var_dump($count) always returns all the database entries**, no matter what the search term is.

---

This is my first Laravel project and I would be very thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: do a `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` after var_dump to check what is the query being  produced and post it here.

Comment: And what does the generated query look like before it's executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try encasing the query in an overall where:

```
$count = DB::table('members as m')
         ->where(function ($q) {
            $q->where(DB::raw('m.member_first_name'), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
            ->orWhere(DB::raw('m.member_last_name'), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
            ->orWhere(DB::raw('m.member_business_address'), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("concat('m.member_first_name',' ','m.member_last_name')"), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("concat('m.member_last_name',' ','m.member_first_name')"), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("concat('m.member_name_affix',' ','m.member_last_name',' ','m.member_first_name')"), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("concat('m.member_first_name',' ','m.member_name_affix',' ','m.member_last_name')"), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
         })
         ->count();
```

Comment: @kringeltorte whey you are not using `whereRaw()` instead of `where(DB::raw())` and  by using `"%$term%"` directly in query builder some might able to apply `sql injection` for here.

Comment: @Avishek The term part of this function is still be parsed by Eloquent to prevent SQL Injection. I am not 100%, but I think by using whereRaw on the whole where clause this would bypass Eloquents sanitising methods and open up SQL injection.

Comment: @Jono20201 we have used a security testing tools called `zaproxy` in which I have seen that  `where(DB::raw())` is eligible for sql-injection , whereas `whereRaw()` is a better option to be replaced. That is why I have commented the same and posted my answer using `whereRaw()`. Please don't take my comment personally. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You're using **and** / **or** together, which of course will fail. Try the following:

```
$count = DB::table('members as m')
     ->where(DB::raw('m.member_first_name'), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
     ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where(DB::raw('m.member_last_name'), 'LIKE', "%$term%")
                ->orWhere(DB::raw('m.member_business_address'), 'LIKE', "%$term%"));
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this code and if you got some syntax error then try to change the `'` symbols here and there..as I can't test it before post..

```
$term = "%".$request->input('term')."%";
$count = DB::table('members as m')
         ->where('m.member_first_name', 'LIKE', $term)
         ->orWhere('m.member_last_name', 'LIKE', $term)
         ->orWhere('m.member_business_address', 'LIKE', $term)
         ->orWhereRaw('(concat_ws(m.member_first_name,m.member_last_name) LIKE ? )',[$term])
         ->orWhereRaw('(concat_ws(m.member_last_name,m.member_first_name) LIKE ? )',[$term])
         ->orWhereRaw('(concat_ws(m.member_name_affix,m.member_last_name,m.member_first_name) LIKE ? )',[$term])
         ->orWhereRaw('(concat_ws(m.member_first_name,m.member_name_affix,m.member_last_name) LIKE ? )',[$term])
         ->count();

var_dump($count);
```

you can use `whereRaw()` don't need to put `DB::raw()` inside `where()`.